# Whole cursor is transparent - why?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do simple thing - replace default cursor with my cursor, this is what I'm doing:

1. I prepared simple 64x64 png image:

[image]

2. Settings from Unity:

[image]

3. What I'm seeing in Game View

[image]

I'm setting this cursor through the code using this simple line:

```
Cursor.SetCursor(CursorTexture, CursorHotspot, CursorMode.Auto);
```

My goal is to remove just black background and leave star as it is, without making it transparent..

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The Unity documentation over [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TextureTypes.html) says that:

```
From Gray Scale
This generates the alpha from the mean (average) of the input Texture RGB values.
```

So the alpha of your image is the average of all of your Texture's RGB values.
Is there a reason you can't simply use a .png image with a transparent background instead?

Comment: Thanks for answer. No, there is no reason but I was simply curious is there a way to have 100% not transparent cursor when there is .png with black background

Comment: use `from alpha` instead and make the black background transparent in your png